# Xor Memory Error

Tags: python-3.x, memory, encryption, xor

This is my simple python xor encryption program, it works on every file i tried except when i used on an audio file which gave me a memory error, how do i fix it so it works on bigger files? The audio file i used it on was a wav audio file.

```
def encrypt(file,key):

    count=0
    encrypt=[]
    openfile=open(file,"rb")
    msg=openfile.read()
    openfile.close()

    for i in msg:

        if count>=len(key):
              count=0

        encrypt.append(i^ord(key[count]))

        count+=1

    encryptmsg=''.join(chr(e) for e in encrypt)
    ext=input('Saving...File Name (with extension)? ')
    file= open(ext, "wb")

    file.write(str.encode(encryptmsg))

    file.close()

    print(encryptmsg)

    input("Press Enter to Continue...")



def decrypt(file,key):

    count=0
    decrypt=[]
    openfile=open(file,"rb")
    msg=openfile.read()
    openfile.close()

    for i in msg:

        if count>=len(key):
              count=0

        decrypt.append(i^ord(key[count]))

        count+=1

    decryptmsg=''.join(chr(e) for e in decrypt)

    ext=input('Saving...File Name (with extension)? ')

    file= open(ext, "wb")

    file.write(str.encode(decryptmsg))

    file.close()

    print(decryptmsg)

    input("Press Enter to Continue...")


ans = input("0.Encrypt 1.Decrypt?")
file = input("File? ")
key = input("Key? ")

if ans=='0':
    encrypt(file,key)
elif ans=='1':
    decrypt(file,key)
else:
    quit()
```

Comment: The issue is probably that the files you ahve been testing on are text files, the audio files are binary and have characters that are not characters in most encodings. You have to handle all 8-bit byte values including problematic values like 0x00 both in the audio file and the decrypted output.